# Create dynamic checkbox buttons in angularjs in rows and columns

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, button, checkbox

See this image for further understanding of my question:
[image: Please visit this image for further understanding of my question]

I am trying to create dynamic checkbox buttons in rows and columns based on the value provided in object.

```
{"A":{"seats" : 10},"B":{"seats" : 8}}
```

Comment: [What have you tried](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)? Please provide some information in your question (not a further comment).

Comment: do you need dynamic buttons? or checkbox?

Comment: @Farinaz the buttons should work as checkboxes so that on clicking the buttons i should get the list of buttons selected

Answer (score 5):

At first you have to convert this object to array, like this:

```
  $scope.array = [{ name: "A", seats: 10 }, { name: "B", seats: 8 }];
```

Then, to transform a number to array declare this below method:

```
$scope.getNumber = function (num) {
    $scope.numbers = [];
    for (var i = 1; i < num+1 ; i++) {
        $scope.numbers.push(i);
    }
    return $scope.numbers;
}
```

Finally you should put `ng-repeat` in your html.

```
<div ng-repeat="item in array">
        <button type="button" ng-repeat="number in getNumber(item.seats)" ng-click="yourFunction()">
            {{item.name}}{{number}}
        </button>
</div>
```

if you have another question, ask me